# What does the phrase "flipping a bucket over" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "flipping a bucket over" in the following sentence from the description (not available online) of the game Taiko no Tatsujin Pop Tap Beat:

> We tried **flipping a bucket over** and playing music on it,” says the
> creator of the game.

Here is a description of the game from a different source ([Apple App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/taiko-no-tatsujin-pop-tap-beat/id1463360242)) :

> Sync to the rhythm and drum away to those notes!
>
> The traditional Japanese drumming rhythm game, Taiko no Tatsujin,
> comes to Apple Arcade.
>
> Sync to the rhythm and drum away to those notes!

Comment: What is the difficulty.  Do you know what "bucket" means?  What about "flip over".  The meaning is completely literal.  They took a bucket, flipped it over, and tried playing music on it (by beating it like a drum)

Comment: @JamesK I assumed that the speaker used those words in an idiomatic sense. Maybe I was overthinking. Thank you for confirming its meaning.

Comment: @JamesK I can see why this could be confusing. 'Flipping over' could mean *continuously*. They perhaps thought it was the flipping over that produced the noise? I thought it was a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Flipping over" is an idiomatic way of saying *turn [something] upside down*.

Evidently they turned a bucket upside down and used it as a drum.

[image]